# Windows 8.1 100% Disk Usage after reboot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, memory, windows-8.1

I recently refreshed my PC and newly installed Windows 8.1. After that I noticed the 100% Disk- and Memory-Usage. Then with the following commands I fixed the problem:

```
SFC /scannow
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

But now, a day later, I booted the PC and the Problem showed up again.
I don't know how to prevent this from happening. I can't always do these commands after boot, this takes too long.

Hope you can help and thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that in the Task-Manager the "Service Host: Local System" is using a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use Task Manager (with full access to "Processes" tab by clicking "More details" if needed) and expand "Service Host: Local System" service. If the service has "Windows Update", it is likely that your PC is installing updates after refreshing.

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is... You don't do anything. It is almost obvious you installed/reinstalled/resetted windows because you were having problems before. On the internet you will find a 100 solutions on how to reduce the resource hogging by disabling this and that, but touching windows components without any deep understanding of what its impact would just reduce the life of your OS. Currently your system is performing some basic one-time tasks and as soon it is over, the memory and disk usage would be normal.

What you can do instead is to leave you computer open in your non-working hours, like during the night. This would give the system just enough time to complete those tasks